# Как нарисовать точку с определённой координатой в BMP?

Tags: графика, bmp

Возьмём для примера классический 24-битный BMP. Требуется закрасить на нём, скажем, чёрным цветом точку с координатой `(x,y)`. Данные по пикселям представлены в одномерном массиве.

Т. к. BMP-файл читается с конца, искомую координату логично представить как `m_pBits[((m_nHeight-y-1)*m_nWidth+m_nWidth-x-1)*3]` (+1 и +2 для зелёной и красной компонент).

Но в результате работы программы все точки располагаются со смещением! Т. е. если точка имеет координату `(0,0)`, то она отображается как `(смещение, 0)`.

Как правильно представить точку с заданными координатами в одномерном массиве?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Несмотря на кажущуюся простоту, формат BMP - страшный темный лес с кучей вариантов внутреннего представления (оцените [длину статьи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP) в википедии)

Так что вам стоит воспользоваться какой-нибудь библиотекой, или даже [стандартными функциями WINDOWS](http://tipsandtricks.runicsoft.com/Cpp/BitmapTutorial.html), чтобы рисовать в BMP.

Comment: Собственно, я что-то думал о [выравнивании до кратной 4 длины](http://tipsandtricks.runicsoft.com/Cpp/BitmapTutorial.html#chapter4) и коррекции в связи с этой особенностью, но не знал, как это реализовать. Спасибо за ссылку )

Answer (score 1):

С выравниванием бороться просто: писать/читать сразу структурами вида:

```
typedef unsigned char uchar;

struct PixelData
{
    uchar B;
    uchar G;
    uchar R;
    uchar alignment;
};

PixelData pixel;

std::ifstream inf("test.bmp", std::ifstream::binary);

inf.read(&pixel, sizeof(PixelData));
```

При обработке просто игнорить бит выравнивания.

Ну и осуществлять навигацию внутри файла:

```
// Игнорируем заголовки файла и самого Bitmap
const size_t header = sizeof(BITMAPINFO) + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER);

size_t pixel_index = 3;
inf.seekg( header + sizeof(PixelData) * pixel_index );
```

P.S. BMP может хранить пиксели, строки пикселей по разному, потому действительно стоит присмотреться к готовому коду. Но если мы имеем дело с некоторым определенным видом, то такой простой "велосипед" выйдет легче.

Comment: Уж лучше загрузить заголовок и взять смещение из него. А то конфуз может выйти.

Comment: @gbg Может. Но не должно)